Working two positions (one being an interim lead in a totally separate office) at the same federal workplace while only being paid for original job
There's a lot of factors here, but I'll simplify everything the best I can... So I have a friend who works as a civilian for the US Military (in Maryland), and has been working the job for 2 years and 4 months (I'll be calling this position "job #1"). They were asked last year to take on an additional role on top of their current job, and was told by leadership that if they liked that role, then they may potentially get officially hired for it ("job #2"). They proceeded to work both jobs for a few months before finding out from a third party who works directly for our Leadership that they were not going to be hired for job #2. Leadership NEVER came to my friend to inform them of this, and my friend has been working two jobs while only getting paid for job #1 for several months now. They have to work on the weekends nearly every week, but they rarely put in for overtime because they don't want to go through the hassle (questionable, trust me I know).
About a month ago, they were appointed additional responsibilities of the supervisory role directly above job #2, after that supervisory role suddenly became vacant. My friend is now doing DOUBLE the work for job #2, working as an interim lead (which, by the way, was a role they admitted to me that they were not ready to take on) in order to fill in until a new supervisor gets hired, and they are so busy with job #2 that they have little-to-no time to complete work for job #1 (the job they're actually getting paid for). Leadership STILL has not informed my friend that they won't officially be offered job #2, and my friend has NOT been compensated for any of this additional work.
This has to be considered fraud, right??? I'm asking on behalf of my friend, as they are simply too nice to step down from these additional duties because they don't want to let down the people who are counting on them to perform job #2. There's got to be an amendment or something under the FLSA that says it's unlawful for a federal employer to mislead an employee into continuing to take on two completely different roles within two separate offices for so long without getting compensated for it, right?? Again, my friend was promised by our Leadership the potential of being offered job #2, but Leadership failed to inform them that the decision was made to not go through with that offer and has instead allowed my friend to continue working this additional role without any compensation or even any promise of compensation for nearly a year now. Even after my friend was suddenly appointed as interim lead for a completely different office than the one for their actual job (#1), and was given twice as many responsibilities for job #2 despite not having enough experience in that office to be able to perform such a role, Leadership still has not come to them to let them know that they're not getting the original (non-supervisory) position that is job #2.
If by chance it is lawful for Leadership to get away with all of this, does my friend simply need to be putting in for overtime and have those additional hours documented to prove that they're working more than 40 hrs/week?? And how would they go about getting paid for this mountain of extra work that they've been misled into performing by our Leadership?
My friend is falling apart mentally and I'm desperate to find an answer that will aid in finding a solution to help them!

this sounds like typical corporate shenanigans BS

he found out from a third party that he's not going to get the permanent position, but he kept on working the second job and the additional responsibilities? While the employer is certainly screwing him, it seems like his own fault to let them do it when he knows the truth.

@JosephWit but the employer in this case is the US federal government.

There's actually a federal law that prohibits a federal employee from drawing pay for more than one position at the same time, with some exceptions for emergencies.  The FLSA might be relevant to the extent that the employee is being asked to work too many hours, but the first step down that road is probably to apply for overtime pay, which you say the employee has declined to do.  In any event, the details depend on specifically what kind of position it is and on other details of the appointment, so your friend should probably approach a local lawyer or perhaps a union representative.

There is a difference between doing two jobs, where each job expects the output that a full-time employee would provide; and filling two roles, while both managers know and expect that the employee's attention and productivity will be split. If the former, not paying for job#2 is illegal pretty much everywhere. If the latter (which at a quick glance is what happens here, given that "Leadership" is the same for both roles), it is jurisdiction-dependent but usually legal.

@Barmar Trust me, I've been trying to tell them that for MONTHS. I think they quickly got sucked into the responsibilities of the role, but now they're so deep into it that they feel like they can't quit. Both jobs #1 and #2 involve a lot of communicating and keeping in contact with outside entities, as well as handling funding and making payments. It's a lot of responsibility and there are a lot of people relying on them for things, and my friend is the kind of person who doesn't want to drop out and end up letting people down, despite how many times I've told them to put themself first.

@UJM, I'm honestly not sure if Leadership expected their attention and productivity to be split as unevenly as it is, but my friend is definitely doing full-time work for both.

@phoog Thank you, I will explain that to them and try pushing them to put in for overtime hours to at least have record that they are working more than 40 hrs/week. Also idk if it'd be a factor, but we do have telework capabilities, however our telework agreements are to work only one day a week from home. They work from home on the weekends, and they often continue working from home after-hours on their non-telework days. Would this affect the situation at all?

There are a couple things I'm not clear on: 1) Is her chain of command aware she's working both jobs? 2) Can she step away from job 2, or is she being directed to do it by her chain? 3) Are both jobs at the same agency/office/etc.?

@cpast Yes, our chain of command is aware that they're working both jobs. I believe they can step down from job #2, but I don't know for certain... Since they were kind of thrown into the interim lead role, I think they're just being expected to fulfill it, but I don't believe there's an official contract or anything that's actually binding them to it. The jobs are within the same Squadron, however they are from separate offices; my friend works both from their original desk at job #1, so they don't have to physically be in two places at the same time in order to complete the work for both.

The Fair Work Act applies to the Commonwealth
australia
A Commonwealth employee, which is what your friend would be in Australia, is covered by a Commonwealth award which will provide for overtime and rates of pay.
Notwithstanding, the award conditions cannot be worse than the minimum National Employment Standards.

An employer must not request or require an employee to work more than the following hours of work in a week, unless the additional hours are reasonable:

for a full-time employee, 38 hours (unless their award or enterprise agreement specifies different hours) or
for an employee other than a full-time employee, the lesser of:

38 hours
the employee’s agreed ordinary hours of work in a week.





In determining whether additional hours are reasonable or unreasonable, the following must be taken into account:

any risk to employee health and safety
the employee’s personal circumstances, including family responsibilities
the needs of the workplace or enterprise
whether the employee is entitled to receive overtime payments, penalty rates or other compensation for (or a level of remuneration that reflects an expectation of ) working additional hours
any notice given by the employer to work the additional hours
any notice given by the employee of their intention to refuse to work the additional hours
the usual patterns of work in the industry
the nature of the employee’s role and the employee’s level of responsibility
whether the additional hours are in accordance with averaging provisions included in an award or agreement that is applicable to the employee, or an averaging arrangement agreed to by an employer and an award/agreement-free employee
any other relevant matter.


For an employment relationship, an employee must be paid for the hours they work. However, that does not mean that they have to be paid an hourly rate for each hour. For example, a salaried employee will generally be considered to have a rate of pay that includes reasonable overtime (as described above), providing that the actual hourly rate (annual salary divided by hours worked in a year) is above the minimum award or national minimum hourly rate for the position. So, for a CEO on $12 million per annum, even if they work every hour in a year (8,784 in a leap year), their hourly rate of $1,366.12 is still above the minimum rate of pay of $24.10.
